# Checked the first item in the loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In livewire view i have a foreach loop that is used inside the radio button and I want the first displayed item to be `checked`. I wrote the following code according to the searches I did. In the inspect element, I checked the page code and the `checked` attribute was added to the first item, but in the browser, the first item is normal and not `checked`, although its attribute was added.

```
<div class="invest-amount-group g-2">
  @foreach($networks as $network)
     <div class="invest-amount-item">
          <input name="network"  wire:model="selectedNetwork" {{$loop->first ? 'checked' : ''}}  class="invest-amount-control " id="{{$network->id}}" value="{{$network->id}}" type="radio">
          <label class="invest-amount-label" for="{{$network->id}}">{{$network->network}}</label>
     </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: As a sanity check can you try `{{$loop->first ? 'checked="checked"' : ''}}`

Comment: @brice It was great bro . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the binding of `wire:model` is taking precedence over the html `checked` attribute. What you need to do is specify a default value for `$selectedNetwork` on your component.

So as an example:

```php
public $selectedNetwork;

public function mount()
{
    $this->selectedNetwork = Network::first()->id;
}
```

If you already have a collection of `$networks`, you could alternatively get the first item from that collection.

```php
public $selectedNetwork;

public $networks;

public function mount()
{
    $this->selectedNetwork = $this->networks->first()->id;
}
```

**Update**

You don't actually need the `{{$loop->first ? 'checked' : ''}}` as which radio button is selected, is determined by the value of `$selectedNetwork` on your component.

To illustrate this; if `$selectedNetwork = 3;` is set in your component, the radio button with a value of `3` will be selected regardless of the fact you have `{{$loop->first ? 'checked' : ''}}` in your `@foreach`.

Comment: Thank you. The front side was solved with @brice help and the component problem with your solution

Comment: @MojtabaDelshad Glad it is sorted. I added a little update for you though.